# How to allow/restrict textview to display only one number after decimal in Android studio

Tags: java, android, textview

I have already searched but nothing is working so i asked. I'm dividing two textviews and getting the o/p in another textview. The problem is i'm getting the answer in decimals. I want to limit the number after decimal to only one.
**htlAvg** is the o/p textview. Thank you!

**My code:**

```
totalCount = jsonObject.getString("counts");
                                //Toast.makeText(hotel_reviews.this, ""+totalCounts, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                htlStr.setText(totalStars);
                                htlCnt.setText(totalCount);
                                try {
                                    float a  = Float.valueOf(htlStr.getText().toString());
                                    int b    = Integer.valueOf(htlCnt.getText().toString());
                                    float c  = (float) a / (int) b;
                                    htlAvg.setText(String.valueOf(c));
//                                    Toast.makeText(hotel_reviews.this, "" + c, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(hotel_reviews.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
```

Comment: try this way String.format("%.2f", c)

Comment: thank you that solved my problem.